# Excel Table and Graph, Looking for data labels on only top 3

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am attempting to create the graph below. Currently it is being completed manually.

The top table is the complete data set.
The second table is formulated to get me the top 3 that I would want on my data label.

I am struggling to come up with a solution to blend the 2 together so that I can get the result on the bottom. Any help would be appreciated!

I am okay to accept a solution with or without VBA, while without is strongly preferred!

Kindly see piture below of problem.

[image: Top 3 Attempt]

Comment: I am prioritizing this without VBA. I have tried adding it to the end, but then it adds those top 3 values again to my stacked column

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop on this question. I could not figure out without vba. Using VBA, I added conditional formatting for the top 3 ranks, then added data labels based on the formatting.